# karma-spec-reporter causes Cannot load "webpack" error

Tags: webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

When my karma config has:
`reporters: ['dots', 'junit', 'jasmine-seed']`

My tests run just fine..  But as soon as I do:

```
      reporters: ["spec"],
      specReporter: {
        maxLogLines: 5,             // limit number of lines logged per test
        suppressErrorSummary: true, // do not print error summary
        suppressFailed: false,      // do not print information about failed tests
        suppressPassed: false,      // do not print information about passed tests
        suppressSkipped: true,      // do not print information about skipped tests
        showSpecTiming: false,      // print the time elapsed for each spec
        failFast: true              // test would finish with error when a first fail occurs. 
      },
      plugins: ["karma-spec-reporter"],
```

I get:

> 23 12 2021 11:42:19.388:ERROR [plugin]: Cannot load "webpack", it is not registered!
> Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
> 23 12 2021 11:42:19.389:ERROR [plugin]: Cannot load "sourcemap", it is not registered!
> Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
> 23 12 2021 11:42:19.389:ERROR [karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9876: Error: No provider for "framework:webpack"! (Resolving: framework:webpack)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my karma_config magically had:
`plugins: [ 'karma-*' ]` set...

So when I did `plugins: ["karma-spec-reporter"]` it was no longer including other the other karma related things... So removing that `plugins` line from the config solved my problem.